# Referring to the contents of a wildcard as a variable in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file to copy a large number of files. I want to be able to take the file and move it to a specific folder based on its file name.

For example, I have a directory structure like this:

- C:/

  - FolderA

    - File1.xyz
    - File2.xyz
  - FolderB

    - File3.xyz

I would like to have a batch file that looks for all *.xyz files and copies them each to a folder **according to their filename**. So the above files would end up in the following directories.

File1.xyz gets copied to D:/FolderA/***File1***/File1.xyz

File2.xyz gets copied to D:/FolderA/***File2***/File2.xyz

File3.xyz gets copied to D:/FolderB/***File3***/File3.xyz

**I know this should be possible using a FOR loop in a batch file, but I do not know how to take the text replaced by the wild card and use it as a variable (so I can create a folder with the same name.)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /R C:\ %%f in (*.xyz) do (
   if not exist D:%%~Pf%%~Nf md D:%%~Pf%%~Nf
   copy %%f D:%%~Pf%%~Nf/%%~NXf
)
```

The FOR variable modifiers give the info you need:

```
%%~D Expands to a Drive letter only.
%%~P Expands to a Path only, including an ending backslash.
%%~N Expands to the Name only.
%%~X Expands to the eXtension only.
```

Type FOR /? for further details.

Perhaps you need to copy the directory structure first with:

```
XCOPY C:\ D:\ /T
```

Comment: Looks good, but best to put quotes around all paths in the body of the FOR loop. Otherwise will have problems with spaces and special characters in path. Also might be safer to append \ to destination in the IF and COPY statements in case a file already exists with that name. XCOPY should not be needed since MD will create any intermediate directories as needed.

Comment: This answered my question. I did encounter an issue with quotes, so I added them. Thanks so much to both of you.